# laravel 5.4 csrf token mismatch

Tags: laravel-5

- Laravel Version:

> ```
> Laravel Framework 5.4.17
> ```

- PHP Version:

> ```
> PHP 7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2017 14:01:32) ( NTS )Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017,
> ```
>
> by Zend Technologies

- Database Driver & Version:

> ```
> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
> ```

#### Description:

My logs are filling up constantly with:

```
Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:68
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

#### Additional Notes:

**From Session.php**

```
'encrypt' => true,
'http_only' => true,
```

**From .env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

My site is running latest NGINX and is using HTTPS with SSL Cert from lets encrypt. I followed this guide.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

So my site is only accessible from HTTPS. In my browser I can see the cookies are being sent to me.
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAqrc.png)

Im at a loss of why this is happening.

**UPDATE:
So I added the token tag to every forum I have and still logs loading with token mismatch error. I went through all my view and added so they look like so...**

```
<!-- Add comment -->
<div class="col-md-12">
  {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('comment_torrent', 'slug' => $torrent->slug, 'id' => $torrent->id))) !!}
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">Your comment:</label><span class="badge-extra">Type <strong>colon :</strong> for emoji</span>
    <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">{!! trans('traduction.save') !!}</button><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="confirmation"><strong>Anonymous Comment</strong></label>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
<!-- /Add comment -->
```

Comment: You've added csrf fields in your forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error when you don't pass CSRF token with your form. You can just add `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your forms and it will start working. For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="#>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    // Your Fields here
</form>
```

Hope that helps! I am sure your error will be removed after adding `{{ csrf_field() }}` to your forms. It's in-built security feature from Laravel.

Comment: whats the difference {!! Form::token() !!} vs {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: You can use {!! Form::token() !!} if you have the Plugin installed! Both of them are same!

Comment: OP updated....any further input that could help me on this. Added a update to bottom

Comment: Yes, this is it. No further tags are required